# http://data.stackexchange.com does not onebox in chat

Tags: feature-request, chat, data-explorer, onebox

When posting a link to the frontpage of a site in the Stack Exchange network in chat, it gets oneboxed automatically.

However, when a link to the Data Explorer gets posted in chat, it does not onebox, but is shown as a simple link instead.

example: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/conversation/data-stackexchange-com-does-not-onebox